# Jquery hover is not working

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'll try to explain as much as possible, i just want to change the src of img tag when mouse is over it{on Hover}; the html is

```
<ul id="nav-tabs" data-tabs="tabs">
  <li id="test" style="list-style: none;" class="active">
   <a href="#home" data-toggle="tabs" ><img src="assets/img/button_home_selected3.png" id="test2"  width="83"/><span  s>Home</span></a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

the li tags are dynamically added using script

```
$('.plus').click(function(e) {
 e.preventDefault();
 var li_count = $('#nav-tabs').length;
 if (li_count <= 3){
  if(counter <= 3){
   $('#nav-tabs').append('<li id="test" ><a href="#tab' + counter + '" data-toggle="tabs" ><img src="assets/img/button_home_plain1.png" width="83" id="test2">Tab' + counter + '</span><button type="button" class="close">&times;</button></a></li>');
} else { alert("Only 3 Tabs Allowed!")};
}
```

also there is one active tag which toggles between the tabs, which is done using script

```
$('li#test').each(function() {
if($(this).hasClass('active'))
 {//Active class is applied
  $(this).children().children().attr("src", "assets/img/button_home_selected3.png");
 }
 else
 {
  $(this).children().children().attr("src", "assets/img/button_home_plain.png");
 }
```

});

I have tried something but it is not working, may be i am misplacing it somewhere, ijust dont know

```
$('#test2').hover(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  if ($(this).attr('src') == 'assets/img/button_home_plain1.png')
  {
   $(this).attr('src','assets/img/button_home_mouseOver1.png');
  }
});
```

Comment: you've probably spent ages doing this but it is easier to do this kind of thing with CSS as this is more or less what CSS does. e.g.http://www.onextrapixel.com/2009/05/12/how-to-create-pure-css-rollover-to-display-single-or-multiple-elements-at-remote-area/ You can set the classes in javascript but do all the image swapping in CSS.

Comment: You are adding multiple Li items with the same id and images too. you might want to use classes instead.

Comment: have u put everything in $(document).ready(function() {}) ?

and also dont try to add jquery.min script

Comment: how do you swap images src with css, is that even possible, and yes i have added the document. ready function

Comment: You don't have to use an image at all. Use a `background-image` on the `li`, with a bit of `padding-left` so the text doesn't run over the top of it. Then you can use a different image in your CSS for `li:hover` or `#test2:hover`

Comment: This is not according to my requirements, so

Answer (score 0):

You can try using `.data()` to keep track of original URL and `.on()` (jQuery >= 1.7) to register callbacks for the events:

```
$("#nav-tabs").on("mouseover", "#test2", function(){
    $(this).data("originalSrc", $(this).attr("src"));
    $(this).attr("src", "assets/img/button_home_mouseOver1.png");
});

$("#nav-tabs").on("mouseout", "#test2", function(){
    $(this).attr("src", $(this).data("originalSrc"));
});
```

http://api.jquery.com/on/

Comment: thanx alot, i got myself working on mouseOver, but if you read my code above, you can see that there is an active class which toggles between the li tags, now i just want the original src on mouseout as it will either have selected image or plain image, thus there are total 3 images. do you know any way to find the original src of img tag so that i can put it inside the mouseover

Comment: Edited my answer to keep track of the URL. This example would fail if for some reason `mouseout` event would be called before `mouseover`, but it is fairly easy to fix that too, if it is a problem in your case.